# Built-in rotation animation of applicationbar in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, application-bar

There is a image control in my page, which support the landscape and portrait layout. I want implement an animation that rotate the image when the oritentaion changed. Which just like the built-in rotate animation of applicationbar. But I have no any idea right now. Could anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways to implement it:

1) Catch the OrientationChanged event and animate layout using Fluid UI feature in Expression Blend. It allows you to make smooth transition from one visual state to another.

```
 void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e) {
        if(Orientation==PageOrientation.PortraitUp) {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "VisualStatePortrait", true);
        }
        else {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "VisualStateLandscape", true);
        }
    }
```

You should also define visual states for landscape and portrait layout. More on how to declare them you may find out from [this](http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/windows-phone-7/layout-tips/#FluidUI) video.

2) Another approach [introduced](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/28/this-one-s-for-you-gregor-mendel-code-to-animate-and-fade-windows-phone-orientation-changes-now-supports-a-new-mode-hybrid.aspx) by a Windows Phone developer from Microsoft. His solution requires additional code but is more customizible: you can choose between rotation, fade or hybrid animation. A code sample is also included.